# Groups with order divisible by exactly two primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group such that the order of each element be $1$ or $2$ or $p (p\neq 2)$. Also for all $x\in G$, $x$ and $x^{-1}$ be conjugate.

I guess $G$ is a dihedral group or generalized dihedral group, but I can not prove it.

Can anyone help me? Any hints are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you require the group to contain an element of order $p$? As phrased this is not clear.

Comment: By the OP's chosen title and Cauchy's theorem, it must.

Comment: If $G$ has exactly $2p$ elements, then such $G$ is isomorphic $D_p$. If multiplicities are counted, i.e., $|G|=2^ap^b$, there are more choices.

Comment: For example, $D_p\times D_p$, a group of order $4p^2$. seems to fit the description.

Comment: Dear Dr. Jyrki Lahtonen according to assumption, Our group can only contain elements of order $1$ or $2$ or $p$, while $D_p\times D_p$ has an element of order $2p$.

Comment: Dear Dietrich Burde 
absolutely correct that $|G|=2^ap^b$,
but $G$ has two other conditions that limit the choices. It seems that $G$ is a
dihedral group of order $2p$ or generalized diheral group of order $2p^b$.
I could not find another group with these properties.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that every nonidentity element of $Z(G)$ is of order $2$. That's the only observation I'm able to make though.

Comment: @hellotinfish: Hmmm... no. If you have a central element of order $2$, then you automatically get an element of order $2p$ (by taking a central element $z$ of order $2$, and an element $g$ of order $p$, and considering $gz$).

Comment: I haven't done much on this, though I kind of hope to when I get a chance. A few observations: (i) the center is trivial; if $g$ is a nontrivial element in the center, then either it has order $2$ or $p$; but then multiplying by an element of the "other" order you get an element of order $2p$. (ii). Elements of order $2$ cannot centralize elements of order $p$. Thus, of $H$ is a $p$-subgroup and $x$ is of order $2$ normalizing $H$, then $x$ acts fixed-point-free on $H$. Therefore, $H$ must be abelian and the action of $x$ is $g^x = g^{-1}$ (see Gorenstein's "Finite groups", Thm 10.1.4)

Comment: (cont) In particular, if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, and $N$ is its normalizer in $G$, then $[N:P]=1$ or $[N:P]=2$. In the latter case, $P$ is abelian.